# Is this the basis for the topology of the complex projective plane?

Tags: general-topology, projective-geometry, projective-space, quotient-spaces

I am doing this as a thought exercise to test my understanding of the quotient topology.

Anyway, given an open set $U \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$, if $\pi: \mathbb{C}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\} \to \mathbb{CP}^2$ is the defining quotient map, then $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open. Moreover, since each point of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is an equivalence class equal to a line through the origin $(0,0,0)$ minus the origin, the fibers of $\pi$ must be lines through the origin minus the origin. Thus the preimage of any set in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ must be the union of lines through the origin minus the origin, including the pre-image of any open set in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, which thus also must be open in $\mathbb{C}^3$.

The only open sets of this form which I could think of would be "double cones without boundary", for example the union of the first and third quadrant minus the $x$ and $y$ axes and the origin.

**Question:** Do these "double cones" form a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{CP}^2$? This would be a nice way to visualize the topology if it were true. I cannot think of a simple way to verify it however.

Also, if I wanted to write this basis for the topology in homogeneous coordinates, would it consist of sets of the form (for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C^2}$ and $(a:b:0)$ in the line at infinity): $$( B_{\varepsilon}(x) :B_{\varepsilon}(y) : 1 ) \quad and \quad (a:b:B_{\varepsilon}(0)) ? $$ $B_{\varepsilon}(z)$ is the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at the point $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Open sets

I have never worked with topological bases before, so I'm working with what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) tells me. The double cones you describe are indeed reasonable preimages of open sets in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. They are of course not the only ones, since you can build unions of these, but that's probably what you meant anyway.

### Your basis

Now to show that what you'd write down is a basis, according to Wikipedia you have to show two things.

1. These sets cover $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Sure, for any finite point you have a neighborhood of the first form, and for every infinite point you have one of the second form.
2. For two such sets $B_1,B_2$, any point $x$ in the intersection $I=B_1\cap B_2$ will belong to a basis set $B_3\subseteq I$. You'd choose your basis as a neighborhood of $x$. To show that there exists a suitable $\varepsilon$, observe that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are open sets, so any point outside these sets has to be a positive “distance” away from $x$.

### My suggestion for a basis

But this definition of “distance” might be a bit hard to make rigorous here in this context. What metric would you use? In order to address that problem, I'd suggest a different basis, namely one which does not depend on a distinguished line at infinity or a specific coordinate system for $\mathbb{C}^3$. Since you want to describe neighborhoods, I'd start with a “neighborhood” of radius zero and ask you this: when do two vectors $v$ and $w$ describe the same point in $\mathbb{CP}^2$? That is the case if they point in the same (or opposite) direction. Which depends on the angle. Which in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ you can check using the scalar product (dot product). The two vectors are equal if and only if

$$\langle v,w\rangle^2 = \langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle$$

since in that case, both sides of the equation equal the product of the squared lengths of the vectors. Otherwise the left hand side falls short by a factor of $\cos^2\alpha$ with $\alpha$ the angle between the vectors. So when are two vectors *almost* equal? If

$$\langle v,w\rangle^2 > \langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle
\cdot(1-\varepsilon)$$

So given a vector $v$ and a “radius” $\varepsilon$, this will define the set of vectors $w$ in the open neighborhood of $v$.

How well does this translate to $\mathbb C$? Well, for one thing you will have to take the standard sesquilinear product (i.e. $\langle v,w\rangle=\bar v_1w_1+\bar v_2w_2+\bar v_3w_3$) to ensure that the right hand side really represents something like real lengths. And for the left hand side you should use a sesquilinear product and its conjugate, which is equal to the argument-swapped version.

$$\langle v,w\rangle\langle w,v\rangle > \langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle
\cdot(1-\varepsilon)$$

Then you can show that you get equality only of $w=zv$ for some $z\in\mathbb C$, and almost-equality for small $\varepsilon$.

Now yo can again check coverage and the intersection property, as above.

1. If you choose $\varepsilon>1$ then any $v$ will give you a basis element which contains all of $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Or you observe that around any point $v$ you have a whole non-empty bunch of neighborhoods in your basis.
2. This boils down to the same “distance” argument as above, only this time you may have a better notion of what a “distance” actually is.